# Z-index issue which may be caused by my JS

Tags: html, css, z-index

On this page that was made with twitter bootstrap: (link removed)

I have a div that has a javascript running in it that prints lines of text as if someone is typing it onto the page. Let's call this div one. On top of this div, I have another div  (let's call this div two) that has the title of my webpage.

I want div two to be on top of div one and they are. The issue is that the JS in div one that simulates someone typing pushes div two down. I want the divs to be on top of each other and the JS to run without pushing div two down.

The problem is, no matter how I use z-index, I can't seem to solve this problem. If I use absolute positioning, the div gets pushed on top of my menu buttons and I can't click them to use the webpage.

This is my div structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:80%; overflow:hidden;" id="panel1">
 <div class="type-wrap">
            <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre; font-size:20px; z-index:0; width:100%; overflow:hidden; font-size:30px;"></span>
        </div>

    <div class="site-wrapper" style="z-index:1;" >




      <div class="site-wrapper-inner" style="z-index:2;">

        <div class="cover-container" style="z-index:3;">

  <div class="inner cover" style="z-index:4">
          <center>  <h1 class="cover-heading" id="name" style="color:blue; z-index:1060;">Julie Seif
</h1>
            <p class="lead" id="tagline">Web Development & Design</p> 


            </center>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What should happen when the JS text fills the area?

Comment: You have some errors showing in the console. As I try to inspect the page it locks up. Does your text script ever stop?

Comment: It does, but not for a long time. I'll go in and decrease the amount of characters (in about an hour) and let's see if that helps. Thank you so much for your response. I appreciate it!!

Comment: @isherwood -- I shorted the amount of characters dramatically. You should be able to open it in the console now. Thanks for trying to help me out!

Comment: Also, when the JS fills the area, it should just fill the area, and the title should just remain dead center without being pushed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#panel1 {
    position: relative; /* to contain absolute children, this must be positioned */
}
#typed {
    position: absolute;
}
.site-wrapper {
    position: relative; /* z-index only applies to positioned elements */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: That comment just made my day. Have a nice day :-) Thanks again.